# Change document root on hosting

Tags: .htaccess

I have multiple subdomains in shared hosting.

```
    -public_html
       -abc
          -index.php
       -def
          -index.php
       -main
          -index.php
```

abc and def are subdomains.
When enter abc.domain.com, it will load index.php in abc folder.

How can I change document root of abc and def so that they will load index.php in main folder without changing the url?

Can I achieve this using htaccess or other solution?

Answer (score 0):

You want to achieve this using Virtual Hosts.
More can be read here https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/examples.html

```
Listen 80
<VirtualHost 172.20.30.40>
DocumentRoot "/www/example1"
ServerName www.example.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 172.20.30.40>
DocumentRoot "/www/example2"
ServerName www.example.org
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 172.20.30.40>
DocumentRoot "/www/example3"
ServerName www.example.net
</VirtualHost>

# IP-based
<VirtualHost 172.20.30.50>
DocumentRoot "/www/example4"
ServerName www.example.edu
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 172.20.30.60>
DocumentRoot "/www/example5"
ServerName www.example.gov
</VirtualHost>
```